# Is it possible to make salty avocado Ice Cream without a machine?

Tags: salt, ice-cream, avocados

I'm trying to make salty avocado ice cream for a culinary school project, but don't really know if it's possible.

I've found several no-churn recipes, but most of them use sweetened condensed milk. I'm trying not to use any sweeteners (or as few as possible), as this will be a cold entrée.

Would it be possible to have some sort of mix made of processed avocados, some heavy cream, lemon and a bit of salt/pepper (resembling a simple guacamole) and have this turned into ice cream?

I've thought about using dry ice for it but not sure if it would work. I might also be able to use a KitchenAid ice cream maker attachment.

Comment: Welcome to the site @JoseColina. A kitchen aid ice cream maker is a machine, yet you ask if it's possible to make it without a machine. I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: @GdD Yes, sorry for my lack of clarity. The KA is just the bowl that you freeze and then put the mix in and it cools down. I don't know if this method would be enough for the ice cream to come out as expected without using any sugar.

Comment: I make ice cream all the time using my kitchen aid and the frozen bowl, with excellent results. Professional ice cream makers don't do anything different fundamentally. You aren't making a custard, and you aren't adding sugar, there's going to be fat but it's still not going to come out all fluffy and soft without something extra. I'd be looking to use guar gum as a stabilizer.

Comment: Simple churns are rather cheaply available, and they do work if used correctly (properly cooling down both the mixture and the element).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the question of dry ice, yes...it makes excellent ice cream using a kitchen aid and the beater in the standard bowl.  It is best if you pulverize the dry ice in a blender first.  You will want to avoid using too much (your base will become carbonated, but you can allow it to off-gas). Add a little at a time until the appropriate texture is achieved. Make sure it is not possible for someone to eat a chunk of dry ice!